# Duplicate constructor in same class in JSX webpack build

Tags: reactjs, constructor, webpack, babeljs, jsx

I'm having an issue with some code I wrote that's utterly stumped me.

The main JSX tutorial available at the [JSX Github Page](https://jsx.github.io/doc/tutorial.html) has an example class called Point, which looks like:

```js
class Point {
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;

    function constructor() {
    }

    function constructor(x : number, y : number) {
        this.set(x, y);
    }

    function constructor(other : Point) {
        this.set(other);
    }

    function set(x : number, y : number) : void {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    function set(other : Point) : void {
        this.set(other.x, other.y);
    }
}
```

That class has a clear example of a multiple constructor types which I'm familiar from my C++ days.  It even has a defined copy constructor, which I think is great.

However, if I got and create a similar class for use by me:

```js
export default class MutableDataStore {
 constructor() {
  this.data = [];
  this.settings = {};
 }

 //Copy constructor
 constructor(other : MutableDataStore) {
  this.data = other.data.slice();
  this.settings = Object.assign({}, this.settings);
 }
  
  //...Other functions omitted
}
```

I get the following error in my webpack build:

ERROR in ./src/stores/helper-classes/mutabledatastore.jsx
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Duplicate constructor in the same class (8:1)

I'm completely stumped by this, since I can't find anything similar on the web about this, unless it seems to be a transient issue.

My webpack.config.js is:

```js
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");
 
var src = path.resolve(__dirname, "src");
var app = path.resolve(__dirname, "app");
 
var config = {
  entry: src + "/index.jsx",
  output: {
    path: app,
    filename: "javascript.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
        include: src,
        loader: "babel-loader"
    }]
  }
};
 
module.exports = config;
```

and my babel presets are es2015 and react.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The naming is terrible, but the "JSX" tutorial page is for a language someone made called JSX, but it is not the JSX used by React or handled by Babel. Multiple `constructor` functions are not allowed in normal ES6, with or without Babel/React's JSX.

Comment: @loganfsmyth thanks for answering the question.  I wish I could give you the answer because that seems to have answered exactly what my problem is.

Answer (score 1):

As loganfsmyth said in the comments, there can [only be one constructor in an ES6 class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor#Description).  You can get the desired effect by either checking if other is set in the construct or by providing a default value for the parameter

```
export default class MutableDataStore {
    constructor(other : MutableDataStore) {
        this.data = other ? other.data.slice() : [];
        this.settings = other ? Object.assign({}, other.settings) : {};
    }

  //...Other functions omitted
}

// or

export default class MutableDataStore {
    constructor(other : MutableDataStore = { data: [], settings: {} }) {
        this.data = other.data.slice();
        this.settings = Object.assign({}, other.settings);
    }

  //...Other functions omitted
}
```

As a side not, I think you might have intended the copy constructor to copy the settings from `other`, not `this`.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful.  It's interesting to see how someone else would do it.  Yeah, I meant to copy settings from other, not this...  Not going to accept answer as it seems my issue is specifically getting confused about the other JSX project that links highly on Google and the conflicting info it gave me.  It just seemed logical that, if JSX was a transpiled language, then people might have added extensions like that in.

Comment: The code in these examples are not inherently jsx. jsx in a react context refers to using HTML like tags in javascript code, e.g. `render() { return <div>example</div> }`. These classes are ECMAScript 6 (ES6) compliant JavaScript.